# Using JavaScript global replace when needle contains slashes?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, syntax-error

```
ver = ver.replace(/http://www.google.com/g,'http://www.google.ro');
```

Seems to be a conflict on /

How to solve that problem?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Remember to **read *and* post** the applicable error message(s).

Comment: Oh, and please read the [MDN documentation regarding JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace You don't need to use regexp at all to replace such simple string.

Comment: @Miszy "global replace": `"test".replace("t","z") // -> "zest"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a backslash to escape the forward-slash:

```
ver = ver.replace(/http:\/\/www.google.com/g,'http://www.google.ro');
```

Answer (score 2):

Escape the slash `/` with a backslash `\`, since the former is used to delimit the regular expression:

```
ver = ver.replace(/http:\/\/www.google.com/g,'http://www.google.ro');
```